# Does refactoring a while loop increase CPU usage?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, collections

While upgrading our code base to take advantage of new features in .Net 4.5, I'm trying to refactor our take of the classic Producer/Consumer algorithm, but I'm concerned my refactoring is going to increase the CPU usage.

Each instance of my `WorkItemConsumer` class is basically a `System.Threading.Thread` that is able to process at most `MaxConcurrentHandlers` items, each of which is handled by a TPL `System.Threading.Task`.

In my previous implementation, I made use of explicit locking to read from the `Queue<T>`. Also, the class wrapping the queue set an `AutoResetEvent` to signal when a new item has been produced. Here was the code:

```
protected override void Run(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var index = WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] {StopRequested, queue_.ItemsAvailable});
        if (index == 0)
            break;

        if (tasks_.Count == MaxConcurrentHandlers)
            WaitAndDiscardAnyCompletedTask();

        var item = queue_.PopItem();

        // "null" denotes a signal to stop processing subsequent work items

        if (item == null)
            break;

        tasks_.Add(CreateWorkItemHandler(item));
    }

    while(tasks_.Count > 0)
        WaitAndDiscardAnyCompletedTask();
}
```

I would like to take advantage of the `BlockingCollection<T>` class, which gives me most of the features I want. It allows a consumer to know when no more items will ever be published and it also allows my to remove any explicit locking. However, I don't have a way to being signaled when new work items are available.

Here is the new code:

```
    protected override void Run(string[] args)
    {
        while (!queue_.IsCompleted)
        {
            if (StopRequested.WaitOne(0))
                break;

            if (tasks_.Count == MaxConcurrentHandlers)
                WaitAndDiscardAnyCompletedTask();

            foreach (var item in queue_.GetConsumingEnumerable().Take(MaxConcurrentHandlers - tasks_.Count))
                tasks_.Add(CreateWorkItemHandler(item));
        }

        while(tasks_.Count > 0)
            WaitAndDiscardAnyCompletedTask();
    }
```

How would you refactor this code?

Comment: I think the only way to tell if it increases CPU usage is to put a profiler on it, and run it each way.

Answer (score 3):

Well, after more resarch and testing, it appears that the `GetConsumingEnumerable()` method of the `BlockingCollection<T>` is actually blocking when there are no items to consume. And it handles the case where the collection is completed as well.

The final touch, it that, instead of using a `ManualResetEvent` to signal the consumer to stop, like the original code, I'm using a `CancellationToken` instead.

This allows me to simplify the code drastically.

Here is the final snippet:

```
    protected override void Run(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in queue_.GetConsumingEnumerable(cancellation_.Token))
            {
                tasks_.Add(CreateWorkItemHandler(item));
                if (tasks_.Count == MaxConcurrentHandlers)
                    WaitAndDiscardAnyCompletedTask();
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException /* e */)
        {
        }

        while (tasks_.Count > 0)
            WaitAndDiscardAnyCompletedTask();
    }
```

PS: I should have done more testing before posting. But, I'm leaving the question and its answer here for reference.